# Eagle CAD template for Arduino Shield

Tags: arduino

I would like to reuse a PCB layout of a design to make an Arduino shield. I want to reuse Arduino Uno R3 board to make an Arduino shield package in my library by deleting every components in the original design (leaving the stack headers intact for the shield).

I tried block copy to bring the block in board to the package window (in create new package) but it did seem to work. It did not allow copying of pads from layout to package window.

I would not want to draw everything from scratch and even pad placement in this case.

Comment: there's a message "skipped unsuitable objects" and the pads are filtered out of the block copy

Comment: Isn't there a shield template in an Eagle library somewhere?

Comment: @W5VO Yes, there is. I've used it several times until the "shield phase" passed. I'll dig it up and find the source when I get home tonight.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is to start out your design with an Eagle CAD template for an Arduino Shield, as W5VO pointed out in his comment.

[Here is a link to one library that contains such a template](http://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit-Eagle-Library), from Adafruit Industries.

Comment: thanks! I might consider this as an answer. It was a little late where I've found Adafruit library after I made the package from scratch already. Though, might there be the case where one would like to make a pcb layout a package library? is this something a real practice?

Comment: @ShawnLe I've never been able to reuse a PCB layout, but that feature would be really helpful. I found [this discussion](http://www.eaglecentral.ca/forums/index.php/mv/msg/46048/143589/) that seems to address the issue in some way. They mention that you can cut and paste a part of your schematics with its PCB layout, but only if you have the PRO licence, because it requires you to have the schematics you want to copy in a separate sheet. I only have the free license, so I cannot confirm.